# How to get parameters from a json Response of Google places API

Tags: react-native

**Problem:**

I am creating a react application. In there I am using Google places API in order to get nearby places. To do that I have created this kind of code segment.

```
fetch(
      "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=" +
        coords.latitude +
        "," +
        coords.longitude +
        "&radius=500" +
        "&type=parking" +
        "&key=" +
        apikey
    )
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        console.log(responseJson.results);
      });
    // this.setState({ location: location });
  };
```

To this call, I have got a JSON response like this.

```
[10:26:09]   Object {
[10:26:09]     "geometry": Object {
[10:26:09]       "location": Object {
[10:26:09]         "lat": 6.8471459,
[10:26:09]         "lng": 79.95188379999999,
[10:26:09]       },
[10:26:09]       "viewport": Object {
[10:26:09]         "northeast": Object {
[10:26:09]           "lat": 6.848494880291502,
[10:26:09]           "lng": 79.95323278029149,
[10:26:09]         },
[10:26:09]         "southwest": Object {
[10:26:09]           "lat": 6.845796919708499,
[10:26:09]           "lng": 79.95053481970848,
[10:26:09]         },
[10:26:09]       },
[10:26:09]     },
[10:26:09]     "icon": "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
[10:26:09]     "id": "e9ec7b7cc1084804271da28697e0342cb86f7c37",
[10:26:09]     "name": "PNH Carpark",
[10:26:09]     "opening_hours": Object {
[10:26:09]       "open_now": true,
[10:26:09]     },
[10:26:09]     "photos": Array [
[10:26:09]       Object {
[10:26:09]         "height": 3120,
[10:26:09]         "html_attributions": Array [
[10:26:09]           "<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/115048704313755953511/photos\">Nimal Kumara</a>",
[10:26:09]         ],
[10:26:09]         "photo_reference": "CmRaAAAAYHzPo3aNai9pQkuhH7dlZIItras7XTW5buvyuqzDiKK6f4WFaOxrLpvtkW2gGcP6j9fTfDaJ2_n2XOOVIUOWuHQ1jDVjtSBahbsIgErIAKhoWyLy2teG4NNQYBN1iwH8EhD49eTzfJVhCMB1WOu2w6DLGhR8tV0F4uVSgMD8pGDn5mU1ImzzqQ",
[10:26:09]         "width": 4160,
[10:26:09]       },
[10:26:09]     ],
[10:26:09]     "place_id": "ChIJQV-fTkVQ4joRRkG7ZUTe7_Q",
[10:26:09]     "plus_code": Object {
[10:26:09]       "compound_code": "RXW2+VQ Pannipitiya, Sri Lanka",
[10:26:09]       "global_code": "6JRXRXW2+VQ",
[10:26:09]     },
[10:26:09]     "rating": 3,
[10:26:09]     "reference": "ChIJQV-fTkVQ4joRRkG7ZUTe7_Q",
[10:26:09]     "scope": "GOOGLE",
[10:26:09]     "types": Array [
[10:26:09]       "parking",
[10:26:09]       "point_of_interest",
[10:26:09]       "establishment",
[10:26:09]     ],
[10:26:09]     "vicinity": "Kottawa Town, Pannipitiya",
[10:26:09]   },
[10:26:09] ]
```

Can Someone help me to modify my code in order to get the latitude, longitude and place name from this JSON response? I tried so many ways to get that Done by I was unable to do that. Thank you Very much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the line `console.log(responseJson.results)` gives you the JSON response that you've provided above. If that is so, then `results` is a JSON object and within it you've got several key-value pairs. To access the value, simply use its key like this:

```
.then(responseJson => {
    let name = responseJson.results.name;
    let latitude = responseJson.results.geometry.location.lat;
    let longitude = responseJson.results.geometry.location.lng;
  });
```